# How to change focus between two screens (2 monitors) with keyboard (shortcut) Gnome 3

Tags: gnome, window-managers, gnome-3, fedora-25

I have question how to change focus between two screens on Gnome. I am using `Fedora 25` and I can move window to other screen by using `mod + shift + right` or `mod + shift + left` but focus (cursor) stays on first screen. I can do it by moving mouse to other screen but I want to do it with keyboard using some shortcut.

I was on i3wm and shortcut there was `mod + right` / `mod + left`, but I don't know how to do it with gnome.

If there is no shortcut for this action, can someone provide me info how can I add it manually.

Thanks in advance :)